# Finding out corresponding points in stereo images of white objects using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, stereoscopy

I'm working with MATLAB2014b and I have to find out the corresponding points of my region of interest which in my case are multiple objects in stereo images which are white in color but no specific shape (irregular in shape). I will used these corresponding points to find out the X, Y and Z coordinates by using triangulate function. By using color segmentation on each image separately, I found out points but they are not corresponds to each other. Also, as number of white objects in both images may vary by one or two more or less objects in either image, so I need to remove those extra coordinates automatically. How can I proceed to solve this?

Thanks.